# Installing PHP Paypal SDK and config file

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I downloaded the SDK, unziped it, then ran `https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/samples/install.php| php`" as instructed.I made the proper settings,but i cant configure the config_sdk.ini. I provided the required credentials like user nsme,password,signature but still getting problem in configuring sdk.tje error is:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: PPBaseService::$SDK_NAME in C:\wamp\www\adaptpay\samples\vendor\paypal\paypal-adaptivepayments-sdk-php-6a4c93f\lib\services\AdaptivePayments\AdaptivePaymentsService.php on line 22.
```

pls anyone can help me in configuring the adaptive payment paypal sdk on my local server in sandbox mode.the config is.

```
$config = array(
            // Signature Credential
            "acct1.UserName" => "vjverma44_api1.gmail.com",
            "acct1.Password" => "1403178489",
            "acct1.Signature" => "An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-AOgp0YRdsTXL1zrOnkEWkTAZeKDm",
            "acct1.AppId" => ""
```

Comment: https://twitter.com/PayPal_MTS/status/476668298721914880 looks like this problem is facing by some one see the link

Comment: will have to check up on this. i think it came down to the dependencies not getting installed correctly. If you install using composer, it should work

Comment: yes composer was not installed properly,actually i had enable curl and openssl extension from apache but not from php.ini file,when i did that it works.thank you for your reply.

Comment: I've just installed this using composer, open ssl and curl are enable correctly but I'm seeing the exact same error.